# How do you sign up for Google App Engine from a country with a two digit international code

Tags: google-app-engine

I know this is not programming related, but it is relevant only to programmers.

I am in Australia and was trying to signup for Google app engine. The require you to get an code smsed to your mobile. For this you need to put in your mobile number with international code.

Australia's code is +61 however when I put this in the form at https://appengine.google.com/permissions/smssend and I continually get an error message. If I shorten the +61 to +6 it goes through but obviously I won't be getting a response.

Does anyone know a workaround. I could not find the appropriate place on Google to ask this question or get an answer - e.g. they have help for all their products except it seems for App Engine.

Comment: This sounds a bit strange, as most of the world has 2 digit codes. Are you sure the + is required ?

Comment: Well I did try without the + and that didn't work either :( but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Perhaps you are keying in your number with leading zero. E.g. if your mobile is 0900111222 the full international number is 61900111222, there is no zero before 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In New Zealand (+64), I had no problems using this form - although I think I typed it without the +.

This was a while ago and maybe they've "improved" their validation.

Send them an email or maybe post on the google group: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine

Comment: Ditto UK, +44, also a while ago. I'd be surprised if this had stopped working and nobody noticed, so surely either Ankur is doing something "wrong", or it's a very new bug. My 1 through 5 top reasons for validation unexpectedly failing on websites are all "NoScript". The input is valid, but the Javascript hasn't run to add the flag saying it's valid, or something equally daft. But Google usually isn't that daft, and their stuff generally runs well (as far as possible) without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As a last ditch effort to get an answer straight from the app engine team, you could try the 
[irc chats](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/f79d9a8678877fe9/70e3b2816a4d9070?lnk=gst&q=chat#70e3b2816a4d9070).  The next one is Jan 6.  Did you post your problem to the google group yet?  Rob linked to it in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The form should work fine from countries with 2 or 3 digit international codes. If you still can't get your phone number to validate, though, fill out the [sms issues form](http://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues) and we'll enable your account manually.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I did that and did eventually get signed up.